# VBA MSWord - Error populating a combo box using a text file

Tags: vba, combobox, ms-word

I'm writing the code within visual basic for applications in MS word. I am using the following line of code:
`ComboBox2.Items.AddRange (IO.File.ReadAllLines(file.txt)`

I am using this line of code as I found it within another forum and everyone in that forum had it working.

However, I am receiving the following error -

> Compile error: Method or data member not found

with the error highlighting the **.ITEMS** part of the code.

I don't fully understand what this error is so I don't understand why it is happening. Can someone suggest a fix or possibly a better method of how to populate the combo box with the several lines of a text file.

Comment: That is VB.NET code, not VBA.

Comment: I apologise. I shall edit the tags now.

Comment: That's not going to help you, since you are trying to do it in Word apparently, and Word uses VBA, not VB.NET. You need to find different code if you are working in Word.

Comment: I can't seem to find an alternative method that works in VBA. I've tried searching and I'm yet to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to load a userform combobox in VBA:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim f As Integer
    Dim strText As String

    f = FreeFile
    Open "C:\MyFolder\MyFile.txt" For Input As #f

    Me.ComboBox1.Clear
    Do Until EOF(f)
        Line Input #f, strText
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem strText
    Loop
    Close #f
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you very much. I hadn't found a solution that loops through the file so this was very interesting. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. That's why we are here.